# Не читает данные из SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Всем привет,есть приложение с авторизацией в ВК,сохраняю данные в `SharedPreferences` при логине,и на второй активити пытаюсь их поймать:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("sname",name);
editor.putString("sid", String.valueOf(sid));
editor.apply();
```

И так ловлю

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
String name = pref.getString("sname", "");
String sid = pref.getString("sid", "");
```

При попытке создать всплывающее окно с текстом

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Добро пожаловать2: " + name + " !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

В ответ получаю Добро пожаловать2: null !

В самом файле строки есть,проверяю через RootExplorer. После перезахода в приложение ,оно выдает нормальную строку с именем.Как можно решить это?

Comment: возможно вы изначально сохраняете `null`, потому что при нулевом "sname" `name` бы равнялась `""`. Так, как все написано, должно работать, возможно порядок неверный. Без большего кода сказать сложно

Comment: @Jarvis_J, ну странно то,что в файле то данные есть,а вывод не идёт...

Comment: Если у вас sid типа String зачем вы делаете преобразование valueOf?

Comment: @Style-7,sid там не стринг,но дело не в нем)

Comment: Вопрос остался открытым...

Comment: попробуйте editor.`commit()`; использовать

Comment: @keekkenen пробовал,данные то он пишет в файл,но не выводит почему-то.

Comment: попробуй так `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`

Comment: @keekkenen странно,но уже лучше)Правда все равно через раз цепляет.При первом запуске приложения шлет нафиг,потом показывает

Comment: у меня все просто, с Preference работает отдельный модуль, который  создает синглтон и вся работа из любой точки приложения идет через него

Comment: ну у меня увы не так))Я делаю по урокам)